# Can I capture DOM mouse events in a Pixi JS app?

Tags: javascript, dom, pixi.js

I am writing an application that is a blend of Pixi JavaScript and just plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I would like to make some of my elements interact within the page. Mainly, I would like some of my DOM elements to be able to interact with the Pixi application by having mouse events work across. I have a JS fiddle that demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

https://jsfiddle.net/brentlyjr/wafzcd1g/29/

Basically, in this fiddle, I want to be able to drag the div elements that are "draggable" over the Pixi app and be able to take some action within my Pixi application. Once I click on an HTML element and begin to drag it, I no longer receive any Pixi mouse events like mouse move, etc.

```
pixiContainer.on("mousemove", myMouseMove);
```

Is there any way to accomplish this, or does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this? I would prefer to not have to convert all of my HTML/javascript over into Pixi to make it work.

Thank you,

Brent

Comment: I have made the JS fiddle a little clearer hopefully - https://jsfiddle.net/brentlyjr/wafzcd1g/44/

Comment: Hi Brent, very clear JSFiddle! The mixing of canvas and HTML elements, in my experience, will be extremely difficult. One way to do it would be to track the x and y position of the mouse on the page, then on the release use the coordinates to place the box within the Pixi container, but this will quickly become complex with different screens and getting relative x and y coordinates. I would agree with your thought, convert the elements into Pixi.